# How to exclude specific extension file or directory be opened another application by org-open-at-point(C-c C-o) in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

My org file is like following.
In org-mode when I use `org-open-at-point(C-c C-o)`, another directory application(Finder in mac) will be opened. But I want to open directory `./` in Emacs dired by `org-open-at-point(C-c C-o)`. `C-u C-c C-o` will do this. but I don't want to type `C-u`.

**my.org**

```
sample dir is [[./][here]]
sample memo is [[file:sample.memo][here]] <-- this won't be opened by C-c C-o,
                                              because there is no application
                                              to open *.memo file.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do?  If you want to open `dired`, the default binding is `C-x d`.  Is that what you're trying to do, or are you trying to open a `dired` buffer of the directory of the file at point?

Comment: Yes, I want to do later one. I want to open directory or file at point in Emacs buffer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear what the problem is.  If you're on `[[./][here]]`, `C-c C-o` should open the `dired` buffer automatically, and if on `[[file:sample.memo][here]]` it should open (or create) the file automatically.

If your goal is to FORCE org to visit a file in Emacs (overriding whatever you have set in `org-file-apps`), you pass the prefix argument to `C-c C-o` (ie, as `C-u C-c C-o`).  If, as you mentioned, you don't want to prepend the `C-u`, you can write a little function as below and bind it to the keys of your choice.  All it's doing is setting the the optional argument programmatically:

```
(defun ooap-force-emacs ()
  "Visit a file in emacs from an org-mode buffer."
  (interactive)
  (org-open-at-point t))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (add-to-list 'org-file-apps '(directory . emacs) t)))
```

to open directories using Emacs instead of system default.

See:

```
M-x customize-variable [RET] org-file-apps
```